# NullPointerException on getting Resource

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, resources

The following code will produce a NullPointerException on `uri = ...`

I tried `ClassLoader.getSystemResource`, `getClass().getResource` or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource`

Don't mater if I remove the / at the beginning or remove it at the end, it still produce a NullPointerException..

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    private Main() {
        URI uri = null;

        try {
            uri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/resources/images/flags/").toURI();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (uri != null) {
            System.out.println(uri.toString());

            File folder = new File(uri);

            for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project structure:

[image: Structure]

Comment: Did you try changing `"/resources/images/flags/"` to `"/images/flags/"` part? resources directory is part of the classpath

Comment: Used ``images/flags/`` and it worked!

Comment: If you ever run this code from a .jar file, it will fail.

Comment: @VGR could you please explain?

Comment: A .jar file is actually a zip archive with a few Java-specific entries in it.  When your classes and resources are inside an archive, they are not separate files, just subsequences of bytes inside the archive.  This means the URI for such a resource in a .jar is not a `file:` URI, so attempting to convert it to a File will throw an exception.  See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=20160908185307951572&a=remarks .

Answer (score 4):

Please try without "resources", because this is just the name of the folder.
The content of this folder will be copied to the compiled classes.

Comment: that's 2 folders images/flags

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for my comment. Since `resource` is already part of the classpath, you have to change:

```
"/resources/images/flags/"
```

To

```
"/images/flags/"
```

Also, you can try relative path like `"images/flags/"`